# Turn Off Excel Backups, Temporarily

Tags: excel, vba, backup

I am looking for a way, using VBA, to temporarily turn off Excel backups, the one whose default location is "C:\Users[usename]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel".  I stress temporarily, just for a few minutes. Preferably using VBA, but anything would be considered.

What I am looking for is to turn off these backup, go make some changes, conditional formatting, change VBA code, or something that might take 5-10 minutes.  Then when done, turn the backup feature back on.

My problem is this.  I want to make some changes on very large excel files.  As soon as I start excel decides to do a backup and bingo, I must now wait 5+ minutes for it to finish before I can continue.

Sorry, I have no code to show.  I don't even know where to begin when tinkering with the inner workings of excel.

Comment: Are you referring to Excel auto save?

Comment: @FaneDuru Not sure, Can also be identified as File>>Options>>Save and in there it is called AutoRcover.  It has a time element associated with it, Save AutoRecover information every ... mine is currently set for 45 min, because of this problem.  It looks like Spinner below has the solution. I haven't tested it yet but it look like what is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**To do it manually**
To turn it off:
o  File >> Options >> Save
o  Make a note of Checked state of 'Keep the last autosaved version if...'
o  Uncheck 'Save AutoRecover Information every'

To turn it back on:
o  File >> Options >> Save
o  Check 'Save AutoRecover Information every'
o  If checked previously:  Check 'Keep the last autosaved version if...''

**VBA**
To turn it off:
o  Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = False

To turn it back on:
o  Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = True
o  ActiveWorkbook.EnableAutoRecover = True

Simple code to do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Private mblEnableAutoRecover as Boolean

Sub ToggleAutoSave()

    With Application.AutoRecover
    
    ''' Save state of EnableAutoRecover and turn both off
        If .Enabled Then
            mblEnableAutoRecover = ActiveWorkbook.EnableAutoRecover
            .Enabled = False
            
    ''' Turn on AutoRecover and reinstate EnableAutoRecover as was
        Else
            .Enabled = True
            ActiveWorkbook.EnableAutoRecover = mblEnableAutoRecover
        
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!  From what I can tell this solves the problem.  Thanks for the speedy answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Perhaps mark as answered then (so other know)...

Answer (score 0):

Under *File - Options - Save - Autorecover File Location* you find the path you described. If you change the Roaming part of the location to Local (eg. "C:\Users[usename]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Excel"), you will still have backup, but hopefully not over the network. Not the answer to your question as you stated it, but it might be worth a try.